# Copy and Pasting specific cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro which copies a cell and pastes it  in **column B** in worksheet("Tracker"). This part of the code run well. However **my challenge** comes when i want to modify the macro so that i am able to copy C2, E1,E2,E6,A8 from **Sheets("Sheet1")** to columns D,I,k,H into sheets("Tracker").

I have my code be

```
Sub Create_Invoice()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Tracker").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange


copySheet.Range("C1").Copy


pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there are more efficient way of applying the code , than repeating it several times.

Comment: What's the problem? You've already got the code for copying and pasting once, so just repeat it 5 more times.

Comment: @CallumDA I am looking for a more efficient way of writting the code, The reason being that this will be later applied several sheets in one go.

Comment: For performance make some testes, but insted of copy paste, try `pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = copySheet.Range("C1")`

Comment: We don't really answer questions on efficiency here. You should put together what you think is an inefficient way and then head over to codereview.stackexchange.com for tips on speed and best practice. Good luck!